# Why is my game not changing players turns?

Tags: java, events, mouseevent

I am working on a tic tac toe game, and I have code that is intended to change to the other players turn when the mouse is clicked. Here is the code:

token is a char variable that is automatically assigned to the space character at the beginning of the game.

whosturn is a char variable as well that is automatically assigned to 'X' at the beginning of the code.

I'm not going to post the entire code as it is over 120+ lines. If you really want to see the rest just let me know :)

```
private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(token  == ' ' && whosTurn != ' '){ 
                setToken(whosTurn);
            }else if(isOver()){
                jlblStatus.setText("The game was a tie");
                whosTurn = ' ';
            }else{
                whosTurn = (whosTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
                jlblStatus.setText(whosTurn + "'s turn");
            }

        }
    }
```

I was following some tutorials on youtube and this is some code that I created based off of some different tutorials. There are no errors in the code the only problem is when it runs, it is always Player X's turn and it never changes even on mouse click. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It's hard to determine from the code that you've posted (please read about the [mcve]) - but my guess is that the last two lines of code should *not* be in an `else` block  - they should always be executed. Right now you don't switch turns if one of the two `if` conditions above evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Did you add the listener to your program?

Comment: No, we don't want the whole program, but as @ErwinBolwidt suggests, it would be nice if you could post a valid [mcve], a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: And sorry for being pedantic, but this: "There are no errors in the code" is patently false. If there were no errors, your code would behave as intended. It doesn't, and so you have a bug, not a compilation bug but a *logic* bug, and those are harder to fix. Read [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  for more on debugging tips.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might need to remove the last "else" statement and just make it run at the end. It seems that one of the problems is that the program is just skipping that and only executing the first block on the first click.
2. Make sure you added the listener to the program and make sure you overrode everything correctly. A common error is when people make typos in their overriding of methods, so make sure that is all working perfectly. A good way of checking this is to use @Override and compile the program.

Hope it helps!